# How to listen for button click in another component

Tags: angular

I have two components in my angular app , one is a navbar component and one is a display component.In the navbar component there is a search button that searches for the entered name and displays the details in the display component.So how can i check in the display component whether the search button is clicked in the navbar component and then fetch the name from the search bar in the navbar component and then display the details in the display component.I mean i just want when the search button i clicked the details are displayed int the display component.Since they are two different component i'm not able to get how do i add and click event listener in display component for the search button.How can this be done?

Here is the navbar component :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse " id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li ><h5 class="myId"></h5></li>
        </ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto" >
    <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 ticketHold" type="search" placeholder="Search for a ticket" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 ticketGet" (click)="search()">Search</button>
    </form>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit ,OnDestroy ,forwardRef,
 ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import {UserLogs} from '../../model/UserLog';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ISubscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit , OnDestroy {
  isLoggedIn:boolean;
  isRegister:boolean;
  private subscription: ISubscription;
  constructor(private authService :AuthService,
    private router : Router,
    private flashMsg : FlashMessagesService,private changeDetectorRef:ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription= this.authService.getAuth().subscribe(auth =>{
       if(auth)
      {
        console.log('logged in '+localStorage.getItem("token"));
        this.isLoggedIn=true;
        // if(localStorage.getItem("token")=="user")
        // {
        //   this.router.navigate(['/chat']);
        // }
        // else if(localStorage.getItem("token")=="consultant"){
        //   this.router.navigate(['/consultant']);
        // }
      }
      else{
        this.isLoggedIn=false;
        console.log('Logged out hhdfd');
        // this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
      if (!this.changeDetectorRef['destroyed']) {
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    } 
    })
  }
  logOut()
  {
    localStorage.setItem("token","login");
    this.authService.logout(); 
    window.location.href="/";
    if (!this.changeDetectorRef['destroyed']) {
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
  }
  search()
  {
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detach();
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  }
```

Th

Comment: you can use component interaction
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: you can change the display component input and use ngOnChange for the display component. paste your code I will modify it

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: you can use a service for fetching and displaying data in display component.on click of search button in navbar u can call the service method which should update data for display component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since, both the components are different, what you can do is create a Subject in a shared service. Now on every button click in the Nav Component, you can emit a new value to this Subject, and subscribe the changes to the Subject in your display component.

This will create an observable stream of events, to which you are subscribing, and pass any data via it if you want.

```
// Import Subject
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

// Consider the shared service is _service


// In navbar component
// public buttonClickEventTrack = new Subject();
search(){
this._service.buttonClickTrack.next(event);
}

// In Display component - 
// Inject shared service _service into constructor    
this._service.buttonClickEventTrack.subscribe(event => {
    // Track Button Click Event
});
```

You can push the click events into the Subject 'buttonClickEventTrack' using next() method.

Comment: But how do i detect in the display whether the button is clicked or not and then only display the details

Comment: When working with Observables/Subjects, you won't have to worry about "how do i detect in the display whether the button is clicked or not", as it will be taken care by rxjs Subject automatically. 

This is a stream of events. A subject will notify all its subscribers, when there is a new value in the stream.

Comment: I have updated my answer, on how you can work with Subject. If the answer works for you, please upvote it and mark it as an answer.

Comment: Yes Eventemitter works as well, but this is a reactive way which I suggested. Can you please mark it as an answer, as it can help someone else looking for an reactive way to solve this problem.

Comment: This has helped me. Got the same requirements and found this!! Thank you! :)  saved my Day. @malhar